# AWS s3 download all file inside a specific folder - Using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Can anyone help me for this one..??

I want to download all files from a folder which is inside my bucket's folder, to my computer's directory with the same name.

Let's say there is a bucket name "ABC" a folder is there inside it, is "DEF".. In which folder there are multiple files available..

Now I want to download it into my project folder "/opt/lampp/htdocs/porject/files/download/" here "DEF" folder is also available..

So, anyone can help me, and give me the code for this..?

Thanks in advance..

=============

ERROR :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::_*construct() [recursivedirectoryiterator.--construct]: Unable to find the wrapper "s3" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/amazon-s3/test.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/amazon-s3/test.php(21): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->*_construct('s3://bucketname/folder...') #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/amazon-s3/test.php on line 21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty straightforward using the Amazon S3 stream wrapper:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/aws.phar';
$baseDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) .'/'.$myDirectoryName;


$client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => "<my key>",
    'secret' => "<my secret>"
));

$client->registerStreamWrapper();


$bucket = 's3://mys3bucket/' . $myDirectoryName

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($bucket),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach($iterator as $name => $object) {
    if ($object->getFileName() !== '.' && $object->getFileName() !== '..') {
        $relative = substr($name,strlen($bucket)+1);
        if (!file_exists($baseDirectory . '/' . $path . '/' . $relative)) {
            if ($object->isDir()) {
                mkdir($baseDirectory . '/' . $path . '/' . $relative, 0777, true);
            } else {
                file_put_contents(
                    $baseDirectory . '/' . $path . '/' . $relative,
                    file_get_contents($name)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $bucket = 's3://mys3bucket/' . $myDirectoryName. throwing error.. thats not working.. Editing answer with error..

Comment: What error is it throwing? Error messages are intended to help identify a problem, not simply to cause developers aggravation; so it's useful to actually know what they are

Comment: And if it's what I think it is, you really should be able to diagnose that I missed a `;` when I typed in this answer

Comment: Have you downloaded Amazon's [aws sdk library](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)? I made a bad mistake, I took something for granted: I assumed that anybody working with AWS and PHP would already be using this

Comment: yes I've downloaded aws sdk library from this link.. http://pear.amazonwebservices.com/get/aws.zip ..

Comment: SO are you getting any errors in the first part of the code? creating the client and registering the stream wrapper?

Comment: It works.. there were some issue in registering the stream wrapper.. Thanks Mark..

Answer (score 28):

Mark's answer is totally valid, but there is also an even easier way to do this with the AWS SDK for PHP [using the `downloadBucket()` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#downloading-a-bucket-to-a-directory). Here's an example (assuming `$client` is an instance of the S3 client):

```
$bucket = 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME';
$directory = 'YOUR_FOLDER_OR_KEY_PREFIX_IN_S3';
$basePath = 'YOUR_LOCAL_PATH/';

$client->downloadBucket($basePath . $directory, $bucket, $directory);
```

The cool thing about this method is that it queues up only the files that don't already exist (or haven't been modified) in the local directory, and attempts to download them in parallel, in order speed up the overall download time. There is a 4th argument to the method (see the link) that includes other options like setting how many parallel downloads you want to happen at a time.

Comment: Your answer is very simple and easy to implement

Comment: There's just a problem: with large directories, script breaks (even without max_execution_time) without any warning. Any way to avoid that?