# download whole folder from S3, using php sdk

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to  learn PHP SDK S3.

I am able to transfer whole folder from local to S3 bucket using PHP.

Is it possible to copy whole folder from S3 bucket to local, using PHP, if yes then please guide me.

I am unable to do so.

Comment: Have you found a way?

Answer (score 1):

```
function aws_download_folder ($bucket,$directory,$localpath)
{
    global $s3Client;    
    $s3Client->downloadBucket($localpath . $directory, $bucket, $directory);
}

//Call Your Function..
aws_download_folder('backup-tanna-accounts','FolderName/','LocalPath');
```

==> downloadBucket() Is fnuction provided by AWS.
==> $s3Client is your s3 object

Answer (score 0):

Acording with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338830/7259765) answer:

> There is also an even easier way to do this with the AWS SDK for PHP
>   using the downloadBucket() method. Here's an example (assuming $client
>   is an instance of the S3 client):
>
> $bucket = 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME'; $directory =
>   'YOUR_FOLDER_OR_KEY_PREFIX_IN_S3'; $basePath = 'YOUR_LOCAL_PATH/';
>
> $client->downloadBucket($basePath . $directory, $bucket, $directory);
>   The cool thing about this method is that it queues up only the files
>   that don't already exist (or haven't been modified) in the local
>   directory, and attempts to download them in parallel, in order speed
>   up the overall download time. There is a 4th argument to the method
>   (see the link) that includes other options like setting how many
>   parallel downloads you want to happen at a time.